# Getting Email and Manager ID in SAML attributes from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

I have successfully created a single sign on integration from Azure AD to my app by creating an Enterprise application using SAML SSO. My issue now is that certain attributes are either not being passed over as claims as expected, or there is no obvious way of adding them.

Firstly: the email has been filled in in the user's profile:

[image]

But even though it has been mapped in the SAML Token Attributes (twice, just to be sure) ...

[image]

... the primary email does not get passed in the SAML (yet the alternate/other email does):

```
<AttributeStatement>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
    <AttributeValue>7204392b-...</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
    <AttributeValue>05f0140b-...</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
    <AttributeValue>Joe Bloggs</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
    <AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/7204392b-...</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences">
    <AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
    <AttributeValue>Joe</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
    <AttributeValue>Bloggs</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
    <AttributeValue>Joe.Bloggs@EXAMPLE.onmicrosoft.com</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="jobtitle">
    <AttributeValue>my job title</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
  <Attribute Name="otheremail">
    <AttributeValue>Joe.Bloggs@example.net</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

Finally, I see no way of passing across users' Manager IDs. It is filled in in the user's profile ...

[image]

... but there is no way of mapping this to a SAML attribute (nothing resembling Manager ID is in the list of choices):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Manager attribute isn't yet available as a source for claims, as are a number of other user attributes you'd expect to be able to use. We have work in our backlog to make these available. Look out for updates in the documentation later this year.

For the issue with the email attribute, you should be able to emit it as a claim if it is populated. It will only be populated if the user is an office365 user with an Office365 mailbox or if they are synchronized from a Windows Active Directory domain with a mailbox Please check using the powershell get-azureaduser whether the mail attribute is set.  The claims mapping algorithm will ignore a claim when the source is empty.

Comment: Does anyone know if "manager" is still not an available attribute? I don't see it in the drop-down list as of Feb 6, 2020...

Comment: I am also interested in this answer

Comment: Hi, any status about that?